# C++ Huffman code implementation encoding right most of the time?

Tags: c++, huffman-code

Evening all working on a C++ implementation of huffman coding, Here s what I have. Which oddly is working most of the time. But with certain input I am getting incorrect coding/output. Please let me know if you see what im missing here...Ill keep looking..
Thanks for your help ! Updated code to fix problems mentioned below...still getting the same problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue> 
#include <list> 
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class HuffmanCodes
{
struct Node
{
int data;
size_t freq;
Node* left;
Node* right;

Node()
{
   data = '\0';
   freq = 0;
}
Node(int data, size_t freq) : data(data),
                                freq(freq),
                                left(nullptr),
                                right(nullptr)
                                {}
~Node()
{
  delete left;
  delete right;
}
};

struct compare
{
 bool operator()(Node* l, Node* r)
{
   return (l->freq > r->freq);
}
};

Node* top;

void printCode(Node* root, std::string str, std::vector<int>& data, int i)
{
if(root == nullptr)
 return;

if(root->data != '$' && data[i] == root->data )
{
 std::cout << root->data +1 << " : " << str << "\n";
}
printCode(root->left, str + "0" ,data, i);
printCode(root->right, str + "1", data, i);
}

public:
  HuffmanCodes() {}
   ~HuffmanCodes()
 {
   delete top;
 }
 void GenerateCode( std::vector<int>& data, std::vector<size_t>& freq)
 {
  Node* left;
  Node* right;

  std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, compare > minHeap;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
  {
     minHeap.push(new Node(data[i], freq[i]));
  }

   while(minHeap.size() != 1)
   {
     std::sort (data.begin(), data.end());
     left = minHeap.top();
     minHeap.pop();

     right = minHeap.top();
     minHeap.pop();

     top = new Node('$', left->freq + right->freq);
     top->left  = left;
     top->right = right;
     minHeap.push(top);
    }
    for( int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++ )
        printCode(minHeap.top(), "", data, j);
 }
};

int main()
{
   int n;
   std::cin >> n;
   std::vector<int> data;
   std::vector<size_t> freq;


   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        freq.push_back(input);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

       data.push_back(i);
   }
  HuffmanCodes set1;

  size_t size = n;
  set1.GenerateCode(data, freq);

  return 0;
 }
```

Input:
20
84
87
78
16
94
36
87
93
50
22
63
28
91
60
64
27
41
27
73
37

Output:
1010
1100
1001
100010
000
01101
1011
1111
11101
100011
0100
01100
1101
0011
0101
00100
11100
00101
0111
10000

Correct output:
1010

1011 
1001
100010
000
01011
1100
1111
11101
100011
0100
01010 
1101
0011
0110
00100
11100
00101
0111
10000

Comment: `int p[n];int a[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must use a constant expression to denote the number of entries, not a runtime variable.  Use `std::vector<int> p(n), a(n);` instead.  Second, `for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` {   `std::cin >> p[i];` -- See anything wrong in that loop, like an out-of-bounds access?

Comment: *Which oddly is working most of the time.* -- It was never working.  You have out-of-bounds accesses.  The problem is that you will  never know it was broken by using non-standard syntax.  If you had used `std::vector`, you could have used `.at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements, and then you would see that your program would have failed every single time.

Comment: That was a typo and is not the problem.for(int i = 0; i <=n; i++) { std::cin >> p[i];

Comment: So I guess you didn't see the obvious error in your loop.  You are invoking undefined behavior by writing out-of-bounds.

Comment: If your referring to the equals it was a typo as i said and is not the problem, its not in the code im using and has been corrected on site.

Comment: Are you referring to something else?

Comment: Then please post your actual code, not code filled with typos -- take the code you are running and *copy and paste it* into the edit window -- don't type it in.  And make the corrections in the original post, not the comment section.

Comment: As i said I already corrected it. I am human.

Comment: [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: `left[i] = INT_MAX;`  That is in your `merge` function.  You need to check your boundary conditions, as you are probably going out of bounds.  I will claim that your program was never working, but undefined behavior (which can be anything) led you to believe your program was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in how the code handles duplicates, if anyone is curious. Code was working just had to make some changes to the comparison in the struct to get the proper output. Thanks all for taking the time to look at and or respond to my post I appreciate the advice as always, but they were unrelated to the problem. I  had to track this one down by doing the huff tree by hand. But solved now, ill post the code in a  bit in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind points immediately to the incorrect code:

```
g++ -std=c++2a -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Weffc++       53367469.cpp    -o 53367469
53367469.cpp: In constructor ‘MinHeapNode::MinHeapNode(int, unsigned int)’:
53367469.cpp:20:1: warning: ‘MinHeapNode::data’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 MinHeapNode(int data, unsigned freq) {
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
53367469.cpp:20:1: warning: ‘MinHeapNode::freq’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
53367469.cpp:20:1: warning: ‘MinHeapNode::left’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
53367469.cpp:20:1: warning: ‘MinHeapNode::right’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
53367469.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
53367469.cpp:104:8: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘p’ [-Wvla]
 int p[n];
        ^
53367469.cpp:105:8: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Wvla]
 int a[n];
        ^
53367469.cpp: In function ‘void merge(int*, int, int, int)’:
53367469.cpp:145:14: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘left’ [-Wvla]
   int left[n1];
              ^
53367469.cpp:146:15: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘right’ [-Wvla]
   int right[n2];
               ^
valgrind -q --leak-check=full ./53367469  <<<"$INPUT" 
==8553== Invalid read of size 8
==8553==    at 0x10A41D: HuffmanCodes(int*, int*, int) (53367469.cpp:72)
==8553==    by 0x10A704: main (53367469.cpp:115)
==8553==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8553== 
==8553== 
==8553== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8553==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==8553==    at 0x10A41D: HuffmanCodes(int*, int*, int) (53367469.cpp:72)
==8553==    by 0x10A704: main (53367469.cpp:115)
==8553==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==8553==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==8553==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==8553==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==8553==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8720384.
```

An empty queue has no valid `top()`.

---

As an aside, using `<bits/stdc++.h>` is inefficient and non-portable; `using namespace std` is also unwise.

Comment: I believe i fixed these things and the problems still remains....

Comment: And did you fix the subsequent problems?  You can't assume that you've finished merely because you've fixed the first bug.  Use Valgrind again, and continue debugging until you can't make further progress; then ask for help.